Parameter Sniffing Issue in Oracle
I mostly worked with SQL Server and dealt with parameter sniffing issue using this procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
    (@Param1 INT)
AS
    DECLARE @MyParam1 INT
    SET @MyParam1 = @Param1

    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.MyTable 
    WHERE ColumnName = @MyParam1 
GO

This is just a sample that I provided. Now I am trying to improve performance of a query in Oracle (Pretty naive), and am not sure if this actually improves similar to SQL Server as follows:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetData_Rewrite 
(
  p_Id1  IN NUMBER,
  p_Id2 IN NUMBER,
  o_ResultSet     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS

 v_MyParam1 NUMBER;
 v_MyParam2 NUMBER;

BEGIN
v_MyParam1 := p_Id1;
v_MyParam2 := p_Id2;

  OPEN o_ResultSet FOR
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
         C.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK,
         C.CONTRACT_SET_ID,
         NVL(cte.Contract_type_Desc, CT.CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME) AS CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME,
         C.CONTRACT_SET_NAME,
         C.TERM_GROUP_NAME,
         C.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
         C.CALC_START_DATE,
         CASE C.CALC_END_DATE WHEN TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'dd-mm-yyyy') THEN NULL ELSE C.CALC_END_DATE END AS CALC_END_DATE,
         C.CALC_NUM_ROWS,
         C.EDIT_STATUS_CODE AS EDIT_STATUS_CODE
      FROM
        (SELECT
          cs.CONTRACT_SET_NAME,
          cs.enterprise_id,
          MAX(cd.GROUP_NAME) AS TERM_GROUP_NAME,
          MAX(cd.UPDATE_DATE) AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
          MIN(cd.START_DATE) AS CALC_START_DATE,
          MAX(NVL(cd.END_DATE, TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'dd-mm-yyyy'))) AS CALC_END_DATE,
          COUNT(*) AS CALC_NUM_ROWS,
          cd.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK,
          cd.CONTRACT_SET_ID,
          MAX(
            CASE
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original') = 'Original' THEN 0
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original') = 'New' THEN 1
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original')  = 'Deleted' THEN 2
              WHEN INSTR(NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original'), 'Locked') = 1 THEN 3
              WHEN NVL(ced.EDIT_STATUS, 'Original') = 'Changed' THEN 4
              ELSE 0
            END
          ) AS EDIT_STATUS_CODE
        FROM CNTR_CONTRACTD cd
        JOIN CNTR_CONTRACT_SET cs ON (cd.CONTRACT_SET_ID = cs.CONTRACT_SET_ID AND cd.enterprise_id = cs.enterprise_id)
        LEFT JOIN CNTR_EDIT_DET ced ON (cd.CONTRACT_DETAIL_ID = ced.CONTRACT_DETAIL_ID)
        WHERE cs.ENTERPRISE_ID = v_MyParam1
          AND cd.CONTRACT_SET_ID = v_MyParam2
        GROUP BY
          cs.CONTRACT_SET_NAME,
          cs.enterprise_id,
          UPPER(cd.GROUP_NAME),
          cd.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK,
          cd.CONTRACT_SET_ID
        ) C
      JOIN CNTR_CONTRACTD_TYPE CT ON (C.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK = CT.CONTRACTD_TYPE_RANK)
      LEFT JOIN CNTR_CONTRACTD_TYPE_ENT CTE ON (CTE.CONTRACTD_TYPE_ID = CT.CONTRACTD_TYPE_ID AND CTE.enterprise_id = C.enterprise_id)
    )
    ORDER BY CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME, CONTRACT_SET_NAME, TERM_GROUP_NAME;
END GetData_Rewrite; 

I don't see much differences at the moment as this procedure takes around 30 - 32 secs. Any way that I can improve to make it work a bit faster?
NB: I tried to understand this but seems like this will require some time for me to go through. Any example would help me to lead to a possible solution. Thanks.
Oracle Parameter Sniffing

Your SQL server method is a hack, probably relying on undocumented behavior. The probability of this hack to work anywhere else is close to zero.

You GROUP BY UPPER(cd.GROUP_NAME) and then SELECT MAX(cd.GROUP_NAME) which seems wrong.

Any improvement that I can make here @MT0? Though I am unable to provide much data on this as this wasn't done by me, am just trying to figure out the things on assumption for the time being. Though the things you pointed, are noted.

Just to comment on the code, after assigning v_MyParam1 := p_Id1, v_MyParam1 is just a confusing identical duplicate of p_id1. The actual SQL that gets run internally doesn't use the variable names from the code anyway, it's just another bind like any other. Also while p_id1 is a constant (because it's an IN parameter), v_MyParam1 is a variable, so anyone reading the code in the future has to consider the possibility that it was put there so that its value can be changed by some conditional logic further down the procedure, so they will have to waste their time checking.

Of all the possible reasons for a poorly performing query, bind variable peeking (apparently known as parameter sniffing in SQL server) is an unlikely reason. And even if bind variable peeking is a problem, bind variable peeking cannot be prevented by simply changing a parameter into a local variable - Oracle will convert either a parameter or a local variable into a bind variable and give it a generic name like :B1 in the parsed SQL.
Why bind variable peeking is likely not the issue
Since the query consistently takes 30 seconds to run, then bind variables likely have nothing to do with the problem. The classic problem with bind variables involves the same query performing differently for different bind variables. For example, the first execution of the query works best with an index access, but the second execution of the query would work better with a full table scan. Tuning gets tricky when we have to fix only one of a query's child cursors.
And in general, bind variable peeking is solved by adaptive cursor sharing and good statistics including histograms. If that doesn't work, then adaptive reoptimizations allow Oracle to also catch situations where the performance differs from the expected values at run time. The answer linked to in the question seems to downplay those features, but in my experience, bind variable peeking problems have been largely solved in modern versions of Oracle.
How to actually stop bind variable peeking
In the rare case when bind variable peeking is happening and we don't want it to, we need to force Oracle to hard-parse the query every time. My answer here describes a few ways to force hard-parsing, such as dynamically changing the query, flushing the query from the shared pool, or using virtual private database.
How to start the long journey to finding the real problem
Query tuning is an enormous topic with thousands of possible issues. If we randomly pick one solution we're familiar with and try it out, the chances of success are low.
Instead, it's better to spend time learning initial diagnostic steps. For queries that run over 5 seconds, the fastest way to get started is to get the SQL_ID and then generate a SQL Monitoring Report. That report shows the execution plan (so we know what algorithms and data structures are used by the query), the actual timings per operation (so we can tell which precise algorithms and data structures are the problem), and the estimated and real cardinalities (so we can hopefully figure out why Oracle picked a bad algorithm or data structure).
-- Find the SQL_ID:
select * from gv$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like lower('%MAX(cd.GROUP_NAME) AS TERM_GROUP_NAME%');

-- Generate a SQL Monitoring Report
-- (assuming we have the tuning pack licensed, which most Oracle databases do)
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('sql_id from previous statement') from dual;


Though I am unable to provide much data on this as this wasn't done by me, am just trying to figure out the things on assumption for the time being and thanks for the suggestion you provided. Any improvement that I can make here looking into the query @Jon Heller?

@user8512043 I don't see anything obviously wrong with the SQL, and I can't tell if the tables are missing indexes. If you don't have access to investigate the problem, and you only have time for one Hail Mary attempt, your best bet is probably to regather statistics. Good optimizer statistics are the foundation of good database performance. Run a command like this for each table in the query: begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('OWNER', 'CNTR_CONTRACT_SET'); end; /
